# Is there a way to make tshark not truncate lines?

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to inspect `http` conversation:

```
tshark -r ~/1.pcap -R http -V | less
```

But here and there I see these `[truncated]` things:

```
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
[truncated] Cookie: PHPSESSID=u0c1ucgkd0463aglsroah7sbj0; __utma=32894956.1912734460.1379368266.1384280091.1384385020.24; __utmc=32894956; __utmz=32894956.1379368266.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); a=ad44ef895a8c9f35cac4
\r\n
...
<div class="clear_fix">\n
[truncated]           <div class="pva_title_text fl_l" title="\324\356\362\356\343\360\340\364\350\350 \361\356 \361\362\360\340\355\350\366\373 \300\360\362\270\354\340">\324\356\362\356\343\360\340\364\350\350 \361\356 \361\362\360\340\3
<div class="pva_camera fl_r">2</div>\n
```

Is there a way to make it not truncate text? Are there any other console programs who can do it correctly, provided they can decode gzipped content?